# Where is a good place to start with making an application in .NET that communicates through OPC?

Tags: automation, communication, plc, opc, industrial

Where is a good place to start with making an application in .NET that communicates through [OPC](http://www.opcfoundation.org/Default.aspx/01_about/01_whatis.asp)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find a good article and a library to start with here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/opcdotnet.aspx

Answer (score 3):

The Code Project article is from the early days of .NET and may not be the best option today.

Alternatives include OPC Foundation's own [.NET API](http://www.opcfoundation.org/Downloads.aspx?CI=281) (requires OPC Foundation membership) or several commercial products.  [OPCconnect.com](http://opcconnect.com/dotnet.php) lists a number of these.

Answer (score 2):

Be careful. I haven't used an OPC API yet that properly conforms to any sort of calling conventions, particularily in the area of freeing memory (COM, as documented, or otherwise). Expect a month of debugging memory leaks.

Comment: I agree, I did some tuning and profiling with the one I link to and I had to fix several (small) issues as I went along, but that library does work. It is a shame OPC is such a huge piece of crap to begin with, but sometimes a necessary evil (office politics here).

Answer (score 1):

SoftwareToolbox's OPCData.NET (http://www.opcdata.net/) claims to be a 100% Managed code solution for OPC Client.  SoftwareToolbox also has some other OPC libraries to help with binding OPC data to forms and web interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

If buying a comercial toolkit is an option I've used the Northern Dynamics [server toolkit](http://www.nordyn.com/Main/Products/Main.htm) and it worked fine. A toolkit will take away a lot of the issues mentioned in the other questions (or at least you should get support if there's a problem).

They've wrapped the OPC protocol up nicely so it makes it easy to use. See one of my questions here for a [type-safe Variant wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1649264/how-to-make-a-type-safe-wrapper-around-variant-values) that I wrote to help with this.